# C# regex to find all the terms that start with @ but ignoring terms with white space

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a text that may contain terms starting with @, I need to extract only the terms which are the whole word and not the terms with white space. The @terms will always appear before `action:`

example: `command @abc @xyz @abc xyz action: Hello world`

The output should be: abc, xyz

This is what I have been working with but I am having difficulty in extending it.

`(?<!\w)@.*?\s`

The output I am getting with this is as follows (colored in grey)

command `@abc @xyz @abc` xyz action: hello world

Comment: Can you share the input values for which it works and not works? What out put do you get when you it doesn't work? Also share your code.

Comment: Hi, input values are the one in the example mentioned above, and I have updated the post with incorrect output from the regex. Thanks

Comment: It appears you wish to match words that: 1) begin with `&`; 2) are neither preceded nor followed by a word character; 3) are followed later in the string by the string `action:` and 4)...(some requirement I don't understand that makes the first occurrence of  `@abc` a match but not the second one ). Correct? If so, please clarify my point 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only allow matching if an `@xxx` is followed by another `@xxx` or `action:`. You can do that with this regex, which uses a positive lookahead for those two conditions:

```
(?<!\w)@\S+(?=\s+(?:@|action:))
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NhzRWA/4/)